# Webform submission via URL supplied data

Tags: 7, webforms

Is it possible to submit data to a webform by providing the data in the URL of the webform page - or some other means of remotely providing data?

I have no idea if anything like this is possible but I am trying to keep email records within Drupal rather than use a simple script.

Answer (score 0):

[Webform MySQL Views](https://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views)

> These views may be useful when you need to access this data from an
>   external application in an automated fashion without exporting,
>   importing, or the use of a web-based API.

View will be automatically updated whenever you add, remove, or reorder the components for that Webform.

Comment: Thank you but I'm talking about submitting to a webform rather than processing already submitted data